# PLS-00103 error when creating object type

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to create and assign variables using following code to create object types in plsql (11g) but facing some errors:

```
begin
execute immediate 'drop type picu_obj force'; 
execute immediate 'drop type picu_obj_tab force'; 
execute immediate 'create type picu_obj as object(Customer_ID varchar2(32767),Customer_Name varchar2(32767),Server_Name varchar2(32767),Time_stamp varchar2(32767))';
execute immediate 'create type picu_obj_tab is table of picu_obj;';
picu_var picu_obj_tab;
picu_var := picu_obj_tab(picu_obj('101','xyz','pro-ssr-qr','12:13'));
end;

The above code gives following errors:


ERROR at line 6:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 10:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PICU_OBJ_TAB" when expecting one of the
following:
:= . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "PICU_OBJ_TAB" to continue.
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: In Oracle 11g you can not use `varchar2(32767)` the maximum length is 4000 for a varchar there. Also: you shouldn't store timestamps in `varchar` columns (and why would such a `varchar` column need to be 32k long?)

Comment: If I am correct the maximum limit for varchar2 in PLSQL is 32767 bytes.btw,is that the only reason I am getting above error?

Comment: My problem lies here

Comment: @MKS - that's true, but only in a PL/SQL context; you're dynamically creating schema-level types in the SQL context, which has the 4000 limit. Do you really want schema-level though? It looks like PL/SQL types would work here, but depends what you plan to do with `picu_var`. You also don't have a `declare` for the `picu_var picu_obj_tab;` line, which is the immediate cause of the error.

Comment: @MKS - from what you said as a comment on a_horse_with_no_name's answer: you don't need to use dynamic SQL if your *values* are dynamic, only if the data structures aren't known at compile time - which should be rare. It should be even rarer to modify your schema at run-time - arguably it should never happen. I think you're going down the wrong route entirely here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with this code:

First: In Oracle 11g you can not use `varchar2(32767)` the maximum length is 4000 for a `varchar` there. So even if the code *did* run, it wouldn't create the types.

Secondly: the PL/SQL code is validated/compiled when you run it. But as you use dynamic SQL to create the types, the PL/SQL compiler can't see those types when it tries to compile the lines:

```
picu_var picu_obj_tab;
picu_var := picu_obj_tab(picu_obj('101','xyz','pro-ssr-qr','12:13'));
```

and that's the error you are seeing.

You have to create the types *before* you run PL/SQL code that uses them.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. If in case I need to use dynamic sql  how to rewrite here?

Comment: You _could_ run two PL/SQL blocks: the first one creating the types using dynamic SQL and the second one using those types. But I fail to see the benefit of dynamic SQL here as you rely on the existence of those types in the "non-dynamic" part anway.

Comment: I want to replace the non-dynamic part to dynamic since the list of values are dynamic.Need to replace 
"picu_var := picu_obj_tab(picu_obj('101','xyz','pro-ssr-qr','12:13'));" 
to 
picu_var := picu_obj_tab(picu_obj(<string variable>>)

I am fetching the values using a cursor like below.
l_var:='101','xyz','pro-ssr-qr','12:13'

Now I am trying to replace the string as below instead of hardcoding the values but getting errors in my plsql block.
 
picu_var := picu_obj_tab(picu_obj(l_var));

"PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PICU_OBJ'"

how to fix above error?

Comment: Could anybody please suggest here?

Comment: @MKS: don't add additional information in comments (especially *not* code). **Edit** your question.